# Getting the 'co-ordinates' of a <TD> cell using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, coordinates

I'm building somewhat of a different website, below is my HTML markup and my question. Please don't be put off by this wall of text, I'm sure it's really not a difficult problem for someone who know's their stuff but it takes some explaining.

```
<div id="0" class="cell" style="top: 0px; left: 0px;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="0">
                <td id="0">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="1">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="3">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="4">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="5">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="6">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="7">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="8">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="9">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="10">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="11">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="12">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="13">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="14">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="15">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="1">
                <td id="0">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="1">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="3">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="4">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="5">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="6">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="7">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="8">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="9">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="10">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="11">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="12">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="13">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="14">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="15">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This markup is repeated in a tiling sort of pastern in order to fill the entire page. A similar DIV might be:

```
<div id="1" class="cell" style="top: 144px; left: 0px;">
    <!-- The rest of the table code here... -->
</div>
```

If you can't see it already, I'm creating a load of  cells across the entire page sorted into DIVs. Now, when a user clicks into a cell (one of the `<td>`'s), I want to get it's co-ordinates represented by: `0, 1, 5`.

In this example, `0, 1, 5` is the DIV with id of `0`, the TR element inside that DIV with the ID of `1`, and lastly the cell inside that TR element with an ID of `5`. I wanted to write a javascript function to get these co-ordinates, but I am at a complete loss on what parameters to pass, and little idea how I can get out the co-ordinates.

From as far as I can think once I can pass a click event(?) to the function I can look at the `<td>`'s parent elements and get their IDs?

If anyone can provide a solution to this problem or provide any input, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Keep in mind that it is not valid for an ID to start with a number. Could cause you problems.

Comment: IDs are also supposed to be unique. Don't think it will be an issue, but it could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [closest](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest) jQuery function, which returns the parent element that you specify.

Like this:

```
$("td").click(function () {
   var parentDIVId = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
   var parentTRId = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id");
   var myId = $(this).attr("id");
}
```

Comment: yeah! great minds.. just that you don't need jquery to get the id of the `this`, simply do `this.id`... much better.. ;) and you miss one `)` at the end.

Comment: true. just kept it like that for consistency to OP

Comment: This works perfectly, minus a small syntax error which I fixed myself :D Thank you so much!

Comment: pleasure. =) You should address the issues that Gaby has mentioned below though..

Answer (score 2):

Since it is not valid to begin an ID with a number, I'll offer a different solution.

Since your IDs are basically index numbers, you can use jQuery's `.index()` method to get what you need.

**Test it here:** http://jsfiddle.net/hBarW/

```
$('td').click(function(){
    var $th = $(this);
    var td_idx = $th.index();
    var tr_idx = $th.closest('tr').index();
    var div_idx = $(this).closest('div').index();
    alert(td_idx + ' ' + tr_idx + ' ' + div_idx);
});
```

Comment: Great answer Patrick, +1. I also found out there is a `cellIndex` and `rowIndex`: `var td_idx = this.cellIndex, tr_idx = this.parentNode.rowIndex`

Comment: @Doug - Wow, that's great! I didn't know that. Thanks for the info. :o) Here's an update using those properties: http://jsfiddle.net/hBarW/2/

Comment: sweet! When I found out about it I was like "AWESOME!" :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('td').click(function(){
   var td = this.id;
   var tr = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
   var div = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
});
```

you can test it [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/c9ZXB/)

more on [`.closest()` here](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 0):

the easy thing would be

```
$('td').click(function(){
 $this = $(this);
 alert( $this.closest('div').attr('id') + ',' + $this.closest('tr').attr('id') + ',' + $this.attr('id'));
});
```

But you have some issues..

1. you cannot have numbers as IDs
2. IDs should be unique inside the DOM ...

Comment: I'm not worried about valid markup, so I don't mind having duplicate ID's within the DOM :)

Comment: @VIVA LA NWO If you don't care about writing accurate code, why do you post here?