# Selecting a TD element from it's ID in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, selection, markup

I have an array called `currentTD` that holds two integers, the first element in the array is an ID to a `<TR>` element, and the second element in the array is the ID of a `<TD>` element within that `<TR>`.

I want to somehow select that `<TD>` and change its background colour. I'm just not sure how I can select that `<TD>` given the "co-ordinates" from `currentTD`?

Thanks.

Comment: .. see now why unique IDs are important ? you have multiple TR ids that are same and multiple TD ids that are same.. no way to distinguish between them ..

Comment: @Gaby, "you have multiple TR ids that are same and multiple TD ids that are same."  I don't see where the OP says either of those things.

Comment: @Matthew - @Gaby's right, look at his previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154532/getting-the-co-ordinates-of-a-td-cell-using-jquery

Comment: @Nick - You should have kept your answer, as it is actually a better approach since OP's IDs are not valid.

Comment: @patrick - Was just updating, fixed it with knowledge of his markup :)

Comment: @Mathew, sorry i had just answered his previous question a few minutes before commenting on this, and it came naturally .. should have put a reference.. thanks @Nick

Answer (score 2):

This is based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154532/getting-the-co-ordinates-of-a-td-cell-using-jquery): you can use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), like this:

```
$("table").find("tr").eq(trIndex).children("td").eq(tdIndex)
          .css({ backgroundColor: "red" });
```

This assumes you have an array like this: `[tdIndex, trIndex]`.  As for your previous markup, remove those IDs, they're both invalid and not needed.

IDs can't start with a number (unless you're using HTML5) *and* can't be repeated, as they are on your `<td>`s.  But since you can get what you want via indexes...there's no need for the `id` attributes anyway, so just remove them.

Comment: @Reigel - The word "coordinates" put's that in doubt for me, I think what he has is "row 12, cell 4" in an array...of course I'm guessing here, could be totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The Id of an element is unique, so you can select using the Id of the <td> directly:

```
$('#' + currentTD[1]).css('background-color', color);
```

Answer (score 0):

If currentTD has an id of the TD to change it's background as it's second element, then the following should work.

```
$('#' + currentTD[1]).css('background-color', 'red');
```